# Can you train the Tensorflow Object Detection API to detect parts of an object?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have set up the Tensorflow Object Detection API and I want to start training my own models. I have my training images ready and I am ready to start creating label XML's.

I want to train the model to recognise lots of different parts of a bicycle. So wheels, wheel axles, seat, handlebars, individual pedals, etc. Is that feasible? How granular can you go in deciding what an object is for the detector?

Comment: Nobody will give you precise answer, as all of this depends on your data, and, of course, the model architecture

Comment: Ok, cheers. I guess I should reword the question to "has any body ever done anything similar and did it work"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this. Your problem statement is like any object detection model which is capable of detecting individual objects like the COCO model which can detect up to 90 objects like cat, dog, car, bicycle etc., Although in your case these are parts of the of same bigger object(bicycle), its possible using same approach of object detection in tensorflow.

Comment: Thanks! I will start training my model asap. Do you think in my use case it is worth training a model from scratch? Or should I train over an existing model with my dataset?

Comment: if by scratch do you mean defining your own model cnn architecture ? If you have time and expertise you can do it, or just retrain an existing model like SSD etc., to fit your needs. You will have common steps of data preparation in both ways like gathering images, resizing , labelling them etc.,

Comment: Ah ok. I don't think I am really confident yet to be able to create my own model, so I will retrain SSD as the best option for my needs